How to sum all values with same ID in R dataframe
I have a dataframe in R generally structured as follows:



Names Column
A Value




Some words
1


Other words
6


Different words
3


Some words
2


Other words
2


Different words
1



How could I sum the values in the 'A Value' column based on the 'Names Column', e.g. from the above table:



Names Column
A Value




Some words
3


Other words
8


Different words
4




aggregate(>A value<, >Names Column<, data = mydf, sum)?

df |> count('Names Column', wt = 'A Value', name = 'A Value') or df |> summarize('A Value' = sum('A Value'), .by = 'Names Column') or df |> summarize(across('A Value', sum))
